# 1st round attack on rc4

Tags: random-number-generator, stream-cipher, known-plaintext-attack, rc4

I'm trying to implement the **1st round attack** on RC4 stream cipher according to [Attacks on the RC4 stream cipher](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=4996d2fbf983a1f5f20636b14db6d27d9a70d01b). For now I am interested in section **4.2 Attack on other key bytes**. It works really fine for all the bytes of the random key of length 8, **except the 2nd byte**. The needed value **t** is always the second frequent one, whereas the most frequent is **2**, which corresponds to the second byte of stream equals **0**.
I can't come up with the right answer. I've followed the paper properly, and all the probability calculations seem very strong to me.

Here I attach my own implementation:

````
def get_appr_sessions(n: int):
    return 3 * ceil(17 * n * log(n))


def recover_kth(key: list[int], n: int, k: int, t: int):
    j = 0
    s = [_ for _ in range(n)]
    for i in range(k):
        j = (j + s[i] + key[i]) % n
        s[j], s[i] = s[i], s[j]

    jk = s.index(t)
    return (jk - j - s[k]) % 256


def attack_iv_follows_key(n: int, keylen: int, guess: int):
    key = [guess]

    tfreqs = [dict() for _ in range(keylen)]
    ts = [(0, 0) for _ in range(keylen)]

    for _ in range(get_appr_sessions(n)):
        o = Oracle(True)                 # True means that IV follows the main key
        for i in range(1, keylen):
            ti = (i - o.call()) % n
            tfreqs[i].setdefault(ti, 0)
            tfreqs[i][ti] += 1

            if tfreqs[i][ti] > ts[i][1] and ti != 2:  # ti == 2 is the case from my question
                ts[i] = (ti, tfreqs[i][ti])
#    for fr in tfreqs:
#        print(sorted(list(fr.items()), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:10])
#    print(ts[:10])
    for i in range(1, keylen):
        ki = recover_kth(key, n, i, ts[i][0])
        key.append(ki)

    print(key, ts, bytes(key))

class Oracle:
    #main_key: bytes = b"zemarin"
    main_key: bytes = b'O\x89\xbd\xb1\x9de\xe6'

    def __init__(self, pre: bool):
        self.IV = urandom(64 - len(self.main_key))
        if pre:
            self.cipher = ARC4.new(self.main_key + self.IV)
        else:
            self.cipher = ARC4.new(self.IV + self.main_key)

    def call(self):
        return self.cipher.encrypt(b"\x00")[0]
```
````